# Filter out records from an array

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to filter out records from one array if they exists in another array. **Products** is my initial array that contains all my products and **productsToDelete** contains 2 products as an example.
What I am trying to achieve is, if **productsToDelete** has a product that already exists in **Products** it must filter it out.

Code:

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState<Product[]>([]);
const [productsToDelete, setProductsToDelete] = useState<Product[]>([]);


setProducts((products) =>
      products.filter((product) => product.id !== productsToDelete.map(val => { val.id}))
    );
```

Properties of Product array:

```
id?: string;
category: string;
subCategory: string;
brand: string;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an array or Set of the IDs to remove first:

```
const idsToDelete = new Set(productsToDelete.map(({ id }) => id));
setProducts((products) =>
  products.filter((product) => !idsToDelete.has(product.id))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const idArrayToDelete = productsToDelete.map(({ id }) => id);
setProducts((products) =>
  products.filter(({id}) => !idArrayToDelete.includes(id))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code snippet filtering out the products that have the corresponding IDs to delete. I added some sample products to test it all out.

```js
const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    brand: 'Brand 1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    brand: 'Brand 2',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    brand: 'Brand 3',
  },
];

const productsToDelete = [
  {
    id: 1,
    brand: 'Brand 1',
  },
];

const productIdsToDelete = new Set(productsToDelete.map(({ id }) => id));
const checkProductForId = (product) => !productIdsToDelete.has(product.id)
const updatedProducts = (products) => products.filter(checkProductForId);

// You can call `setProducts(updatedProducts);` from this point in the stack forward.

console.log(updatedProducts(products));
```